# Simplified/automated datafile free disk space reclaim

Tags: oracle, diskspace

On Oracle version 11g:

After Googling, I can't find a simple way to reclaim free space after deleting a table.

I've found a lot of explanations, telling how the datafile becomes fragmented, the big stack of boring queries you have to run in order to move the "empty space" at end of the datafile (table by table... even when you have 200 tables !?).

Then you have to reduce the datafile size by "guessing" by how much you can reduce it, or you must know exactly what is your "block size"... And finally you should not forget to "rebuild the indexes".

See for example : http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:54178027703899

Is there a simple PL/SQL procedure which, given a tablespace name or datafile name, would to that job? Or any similar Oracle tool?

Comment: Might be better asked on dbas.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Copied to dba.stackexchange.com: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/simplified-automated-datafile-free-disk-space-reclaim - this one can be closed